# Energy recovery from refinery cooling tower

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics

Is there any possibility of recovering exhaust energy from a cooling tower by putting a wind turbine above it?  Would this affect the performance of the cooling tower?

Comment: Any energy that would be recovered would be very small, meaning that there is no way to pay for the capital expense in any small amount of time.  Refinery managers will never allocate money to a project that will not quickly pay for itself, and produce a positive cash flow.

Comment: jon, do you work in a refinery?

Comment: yes i am working in a refinery

Comment: presently it is mandatory to use or recover renewable source of energy at least 10% of total energy used in an establishment otherwise we have to pay lots of money to govt. against non-fulfillment of guidelines. so i think the project will be fisible

Comment: jon, I suggest you investigate variable speed fans on the cooling towers.  It is a well known fact that the fan power requirements scale as the cube of fan speed.  Thus, if you are able to trim the fans to half speed, the associated motors will use 1/8 of the energy of full speed.  This type of project has MUCH more chance of success than what you originally proposed, and it eliminates the need to try energy recovery from low speed air exiting the fans.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a cooling tower is to cool some fluid (I'll assume water), and it achieves this by blowing cold air past the water. For optimum cooling, you want as much air to go through the tower as fast as possible. These all sound like things that a turbine would like as well, but installing a turbine would hurt the tower's cooling effectiveness: in taking energy from the air stream, the turbine would slow the airflow and reduce the tower's ability to cool water. A cooling tower is therefore better off without a turbine on top.